# cannot execute binary file of golang bootstrap installer

Tags: go

I'm using the instructions in [this blog post](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/09/04/building-go-1-5-on-the-raspberry-pi), which is intended for installing go 1.5 on the Raspberry Pi, to install golang on my Chromebook (which has ChrUbuntu not Chromium installed). The technique recommended in the blog post is to install a Golang 1.4 bootstrap compiler [available here](http://dave.cheney.net/paste/go-linux-arm-bootstrap-c788a8e.tbz%20%7C%20tar%20xj) and then use that to build golang 1.5 (as you need a version of go installed to build 1.5). I tried this on the Raspberry pi and it worked, but when I ran this command from /go/src on ChrUbuntu

```
 env GO_TEST_TIMEOUT_SCALE=10 GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$HOME/go-linux-arm-bootstrap ./all.bash
```

It gave me this output

```
 env GO_TEST_TIMEOUT_SCALE=10 GOROOT_BOOTSTRAP=$HOME/go-linux-arm-bootstrap ./all.bash
# Building C bootstrap tool.
cmd/dist
./make.bash: line 121: /home/user/go-linux-arm/bootstrap/bin/go cannot execute binary file
```

Why am I getting this error message (is it because it's not compatible with ChrUbuntu) and how to do what I am trying to do. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tough one to help with remotely. My first thought, since I own a chromebook and run go on it fine (natively, kinda, as well as dual-booted in Arch), is to wonder about the architecture. I know different models vary, but my architecture is amd64 rather than arm. Is it possible you've got the wrong bootstrap architecture?

Comment: Alternatively: I don't the details of the ChrUbuntu project and if the packages are restricted, but can you not install go through apt-get?